# Raspagem de dados de um site com filtragem tables dinâmicas

Tags: ajax, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scraping

A plataforma de busca dos programas conceituados na Capes possui uma filtragem dinâmica para a própria consulta. Gostaria de saber como eu coleto os dados de uma saída utilizando Python. Por que, utilizando apenas as libs bs4 e requests eu não consigo obter saída desses dados (creio que justamente por ser uma consulta dinâmica). Por conta do JS e o Ajax.

[Site de consulta programas CAPES](https://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/public/consultas/coleta/programa/listaPrograma.jsf)

Em Python, como poderia raspar os dados dessa consulta com uma filtragem específica ?

**EDIT:** Bom, pelo visto, consegui aprender um pouco mais a mexer com a lib Selenium e progredi certo percurso. 
Meu código até então:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chrome_path=r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/public/consultas/coleta/programa/listaPrograma.jsf")
driver.find_element_by_id("""form:checkAreaAv""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="form:autocompleteAreaAv:input"]""").send_keys("CIÊNCIA DA COMPUTAÇÃO")
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="form:autocompleteAreaAv:listbox"]""")).select_by_value(2)
f.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="form:consultar"]""").click()
results=f.find_elements_by_class_name("resultados")
```

Porém, estou com uma dificuldade de selecionar um item de um menu drop-down no próprio texto da **Área de Avaliação**.

Comment: Sua pergunta esta generica demais, o que vc ja tentou? quais os problemas encontrou? ou seria essa pergunta totalmente fora do contexto desse "board"?

Comment: Eu ja tentei utilizando a lib request + beautiful soup. Porém, ele não indica nenhum resultado, mesmo indicando o exato caminho do HTML.

Comment: Mostre o codigo que vc tentou.

Comment: Bom, eu segui a dica do amigo Denis ali embaixo, e consegui aprender a mexer com webdriver do selenium e capturar os dados. De qualquer forma, ainda n consegui porque no meio do caminho me encara um texto com um menu drop-down de options para filtrar o resultado, mas creio que estou no caminho certo agor

Comment: Repito... Mostre o codigo q vc tentou e qual foi a dificuldade, se não vc não esta querendo ser adjudado, esta querendo que resolvam seu problema. Triste.

Comment: Editei a pergunta agora, com meu código até então.

Comment: A minha dúvida seria quando uso a função select do selenium, ele acaba não selecionando por valor da listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez poderia usar o [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) para emular a utilização e capturar os dados. Se a quantidade de dados a serem capturadas não for muito grande, com certeza o Selenium pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Usei o selenium, porém, meu código ainda resta algo que estou com dificuldade de solucionar, editei a pergunta para a demonstração do mesmo.

Comment: Faça o seguinte:

1. Insira algo no campo até que algum resultado no dropdown apareça.
2. Clique com o direito no resultado e escolha inspecionar.
3.  Você terá informações do campo. Então estude a melhor maneira de capturá-la com o Selenium, baseando-se no tipo do campo.